# JavaScript: detect if Chrome is being controlled by automated test tools

Tags: javascript, selenium, google-chrome, cypress

When a Chrome instance is being controlled by automated test tools (e.g. Cypress or Selenium), it will display a banner indicating this is the case:

[image]

However, how can I detect if this is true for the current Chrome instance via JavaScript?

Answer (score 1):

"Chrome is being controlled by.." message is shown when a user using `WebDriver`.

When using WebDriver you can use `navigator.webdriver` to detect if the user using webdriver

But be aware that it can be bypassed (people can edit the hex of the WebDriver).

The `navigator.webdriver` will return true if the user using WebDriver

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Navigator/webdriver